# переменная с кириллицей и тире не хочет работать через onclick и вызывать функцию

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть переменная nomerZakaza ="ЧСФР-052358" в   addMarkerCluster  , у нее тип строка , но когда я передаю ее в функцию, функция не воспринимает тире.
Как правильно в таком случае передавать переменную в функцию?

При передачи в консоле ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function onSelectOrder(nomerZakaza){
    if (MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.get('balloonContentFooter')=='<button class="button-select" onclick="onSelectOrder(' + nomerZakaza + ')">Выбрать</button>') {
        MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.set('balloonContentFooter','<button class="button-select" onclick="onSelectOrder( ' + "'"+nomerZakaza+"'" + ' )">Удалить</button>')
        var valInp = MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.get('id');
        var volume = MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.get('balloonContent');
        } else {
        MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.set('balloonContentFooter','<button class="button-select" onclick="onSelectOrder(' + nomerZakaza + ')">Выбрать</button>')
        var valInpDel = MarkList[nomerZakaza].properties.get('id'); 
    }
    
   function addMarkerCluster(coordin1, coordin2, nameAgent, opisanie, adressAgent, nomerZakaza, volume, driver, badError) {
    const mark = new ymaps.Placemark([coordin1, coordin2],{
        id: nomerZakaza,
        balloonContent: volume,
        address: adressAgent,
        object: nomerZakaza,
        comment: opisanie,
        balloonContentBody:  nameAgent + '<br>'  + adressAgent + '<br>' + 'объем: ' + volume + '<br>' + 'комметарий менеджера: '+ opisanie + '<br>'+ '  <strong>' + driver + '</strong>',
        // balloonContentFooter: '<p class="buttons {{ properties.state }}"><button class="button-select" onclick="onSelectOrder(' + nomerZakaza + ')">Выбрать</button><button class="button-delete" onclick="onDeleteOrder(' + nomerZakaza + ')">Удалить</button></p>'  ,
        balloonContentFooter: '<button class="button-select" onclick="onSelectOrder(' + nomerZakaza + ')">Выбрать</button>',
        clusterCaption: '  <strong>' + nomerZakaza + '<br>' + '<mark>' + badError +'</mark>'+ '</strong>'
    },{
        preset: 'islands#violetIcon'
    })
    MarkList[nomerZakaza] = mark
    arr1.push(mark)
    clusterer.add(arr1);
    cluster.refresh(clusterer)
}
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150173/discussion-on-question-by-vasijkeee--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.